# How to save string into file in FormFile format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have got controller whitch support uploadnig files. Inside it is a method whitch validate data in file.

```
IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
```

It works perfectly. Now I need to write test to this controller. And my question is: how to deliver file form disc into my function in `FormFile` format?

Comment: `FormFile` does not seem to be part of the default .NET class library. Please add to your question: (1) a link to the documentation of the `FormFile` class and (2) a tag for the third-party library you are using.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. My bad it is from .Net Core

Comment: My answer is a general one - im not sure where your "string" is from, and how it relates to this question.

Comment: @Jamiec Its file content. All text in file in `string` format.

Comment: @MKasprzyk - ah right, obviously! Updated my answer with some more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the reason to implement something like this as an interface, is to *help* you be able to test it.

You can easily write a test class which implements `IFormFile` to pass to your controller method from a test

```
public class TestFormFile : IFormFile
{
   // Implementation here
}
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Http/IFormFile/) for all the properties & methods you must implement.

Your implementation should probably take your string content in the constructor, and use it when implementing the 3 methods on `IFormFile` - for example the one for `OpenReadStream` can be implemnted with use of `MemoryStream` (Note, you'll need to know the encoding of your test string!):

```
public class TestFormFile : IFormFile
{
    private string testFileContents;

    public TestFormFile(string testFileContent)
    {
        this.testFileContents = testFileContents;
    }

    public Stream OpenReadStream()
    {
       return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testFileContents));
    }

    // Implement Other methods and properties.
}
```